# Node.js Express: Unexpected behavior when calling /newblogs endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is the code I was working on:

```
import express from 'express'
import * as blogControler from '../controler/blogControler.js'
import * as authControler from '../controler/authControler.js'

const blogRouter= express.Router()

blogRouter.use(authControler.isVerified)

blogRouter.route('/allblogs').get(blogControler.showallblogs)
blogRouter.route('/:id').get(blogControler.find_blog)
blogRouter.route('/newblogs').get(blogControler.newpost)


export default blogRouter;
```

When I tried to hit /newblogs endpoint it was throwing error.

I tried many things and finally when I changed the position of /newblogs endpoint it worked!!
The updated code is given below -

```
import express from 'express'
import * as blogControler from '../controler/blogControler.js'
import * as authControler from '../controler/authControler.js'

const blogRouter= express.Router()

blogRouter.use(authControler.isVerified)

blogRouter.route('/allblogs').get(blogControler.showallblogs)
blogRouter.route('/newblogs').get(blogControler.newpost)
blogRouter.route('/:id').get(blogControler.find_blog)

export default blogRouter;
```

It is confusing `/:id` and `/newblogs`. I noticed that when I was calling `/newblogs` in the first code snipet it was calling function related to `/:id`. I think it is confusing the route between `/:id` and `/newblogs`.

But *why* is that happening?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow, as you are new here, I would recommend you to take a look at [StackOverflow Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), it will help you to take an idea about how to ask a perfect post and give you an idea about the context of formating the post to let it readable and understandable.

Comment: about your NodeJs issue:  expressJs path's order is very important, take in consideration to always make dynamic routes like `/:id` as the last ones, and priorize the static route's paths as first ones. Why ? because:  expressJs will interpret your code from top to bottom,  means if you define `/:id` before `/newblog`, and then call `/newblog`, the expressJs will map `/newblog` to `/:id` while it is waiting for `/some_thing` (:id) . that's why fixing the orders will correct the problem .

Comment: for more details, feel free to take a look at this post: [Order of routes when using parameters in ExpressJS](https://gabrieleromanato.name/order-of-routes-when-using-parameters-in-expressjs)

Answer (score 1):

This is happening beacuse the router interprets a requst to /newblogs as a parameter of /:id, so basicly like someone trying to get a blog with the id of `newblogs`. As you showed this can be fixed simply by changing the order of the routes.

Answer (score 1):

This issue due to  `/:id` overwrite `/newblog` URL because `/:id` is dynamic URl

so if you changing the order of the routes you will still get conflict between `/:id` and `/newblog`

so i suggest change `/:id` URL as below it will solve issue

```js
    import express from 'express'
    import * as blogControler from '../controler/blogControler.js'
    import * as authControler from '../controler/authControler.js'

    const blogRouter= express.Router()

    blogRouter.use(authControler.isVerified)

    blogRouter.route('/allblogs').get(blogControler.showallblogs)

    //route changed
    blogRouter.route('/blogs/:id').get(blogControler.find_blog)
    blogRouter.route('/newblogs').get(blogControler.newpost)
```